# DateSetListener object cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

Here is my code  : The datepickobj declared within the onClick() method doesnt seem to recognize the object created in the DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.
I get a 'datepickobj cannot be resolved to a variable' error! Any help much appreciated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        userdate =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_datespent);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Date da = new Date();
        userdate.setText( sdf.format(da));
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    



        Button changeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_for_cal);
        changeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 DatePickerDialog(this, datepickobj,  cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                userdate.setText("");
            }
        });

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datepickobj = new OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cday = dayOfMonth;
                cmonth = monthOfYear + 1;
                cyear = year;

                userdate.setText("Choosen date is :" + cday + "/" + cmonth + "/" + cyear);      
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `datepickobj` so it is before the line

```
changeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

And declare it as `final`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  userdate =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_datespent);
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  Date da = new Date();
  userdate.setText( sdf.format(da));
  final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    

  final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datepickobj = new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      cday = dayOfMonth;
      cmonth = monthOfYear + 1;
      cyear = year;

      userdate.setText("Choosen date is :" + cday + "/" + cmonth + "/" + cyear);      
    }
  };

  Button changeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_for_cal);
  changeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      DatePickerDialog(this, datepickobj,  cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                       cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
      userdate.setText("");
    }
  });
}
```

Method scoped variables in Java follow a linear pattern in terms of declaration, you cannot declare a variable at the end of a method and attempt to use it any place before.

The `final` modifier is used because you are using the `datepickobj` within an anonymous inner class. If you made `datepickobj` an instance variable (that is to say, outside any methods, at the root of the class), the `final` modifier would not be needed to get the code to compile.